# How to I get scripts to run?

Tags: javascript, package.json

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "watch": "nodemon",
    "seed": "node server/seeders/seeds.js"
  },
```

I downloaded some code that already has scripts. I put the code in a folder called server and now I am not able to run the scripts. (See [a screenshot of my editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOxIu.png).) How can I run them and still keep them in the folder that I made?

Comment: have you tried running `npm start`?

Comment: Your screenshot is not helpful.  What _would_ be helpful is if you gave us the exact command you tried to run, and the exact error message that you got as a result (not as an image.)  Furthermore, it's worth describing why you think what you did will work, and what it is that you don't understand about the error that you got -- especially since the majority of error messages are actually quite helpful towards identifying the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run in root directory

```sh
npm start
```

Run

```sh
npm run start
```

To watch if you change file it will restart your application